# why do I have System.Int32[] as output when I try to return my array?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to find the unique numbers inside of an array. and return it as an array of integers: for example if I have this array: `arr = [2,3,2,6,2]`, my output should be: `[3,6]`

```
    public static int[] unique(int[] arr)
    {
        
          var uniqueList = arr.GroupBy(n => n).Where(item => item.Count() == 1).Select(item => item.Key);

    
        int[] r = uniqueList.OrderBy(item => item).ToArray();
        foreach (int item2 in r)
        {
            r = uniqueList.OrderBy(item => item2).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.WriteLine(item2);      
        }  
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Where(item => item.Count() == 1)` will return the items the items which appears only once in the list. 3 and 6 appear only once while 2 is thrice

Comment: Because `r.ToString()` does not format the array elements as a string. In other words `Array.ToString` writes the element type name. You'll have to build a string yourself. eg `$"[{string.Join(", ",r.Select(i => i.ToString())}]"`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I output it as an array? e,g: return arr;

Comment: `foreach (int item2 in r){ r = ... }` you are also changing r inside the loop.

Comment: _"how do I output it as an array"_ - what does that mean? `Console.WriteLine` writes a `string` (text) because that's what the console is (textual output). Saying that you want to output an array makes no sense here.

Comment: What do you mean by "output it as an array"? It already is an array so you don't have to do anything to it to make it an array. If you're actually asking how you view the contents of the array then JeremyLakeman has shown you that.

Comment: The code in the for loop looks strange.  Is this line supposed to be there?  "r = uniqueList.OrderBy(item => item2).ToArray();".  It is ordering the elements with a delegate that always returns the same value (item2).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one shot by adding `OrderBy` and `ToArray` to your Linq. I would also give a better name to my method and organize my linq for readability sake.

```
static int[] GetUniqueNumbers(int[] arr)
{
    var uniqueList = arr
        .GroupBy(n => n)
        .Where(item => item.Count() == 1)
        .Select(item => item.Key)
        .OrderBy(e => e)
        .ToArray();

    return uniqueList;
}
```

To testing it:

```
var arr = new int[] { 2, 6, 2, 3, 2 };

var numbers = GetUniqueNumbers(arr);

foreach (var i in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

And the output is

```
3
6
```